# Incorrect number of dimensions in creating multiple plots using a for loop with ggplot2

Tags: r, loop, data-frame, rstudio, ggplot

I'm trying to map out all these different "solutions" from the prioritize model using ggplot. (To preface I'm very new to R so perhaps my code/methods are extremely rudimentary and why I'm also not able to decipher the errors completely). What I was doing before was copying and pasting the code to make a ggplot map for each solution (named s1, s2, s3 etc..). It was very time-consuming - (I think due to the size of the datasets I'm loading). I don't mind if it takes even longer to display all 10, but id rather automate it and let it run all night (like in a for loop or function) as opposed to hanging around my computer all day and ensuring that the plot is done and saved, and then having to click ctrl + enter to run the next plot.

**Option 1**: Putting the solutions into a list. and I'm running through the list in a for loop to create the map:

```
solutions <- list("s1" = s1, "s2" = s2, "s3" = s3, "s4" = s4, "s5" = s5, "s10" = s10, "s11" = s11, "s12" = s12)

for (i in 1:length(solutions)) {
  ggplot() + 
    geom_sf(data = range, size = 1, color = "black", fill = "NA") +
    geom_sf(data = fire, size = 0.25, color = "darkred",
            fill = "darkred", show.legend = 'poly') +
    geom_sf(data = poly, size = 0.25, fill = "darkorange", color = "darkorange") +
    geom_sf(data = IFL, size = 0.25, fill = 'darkseagreen', alpha = 0.7, color = "darkseagreen") +
    geom_sf(data = protected_areas, size = 0.5, alpha = 0.4, fill = "forestgreen", color = "forestgreen") +
    geom_sf(data = i[, "solution_1"], aes(fill = solution_1)) + # this is the data from the solution in Prioritizr. It essentially adds a column called solution_1 and if a planning unit is selected for restoration it will be populated with a value of 1. 
    geom_sf(data = linear, size = 0.5, color = "darkgoldenrod1") +
    ggtitle('Test solution') + 
    scale_fill_gradient(low = NA, high = "blue") + 
    theme_void() + 
  sys.sleep(2)
}
```

**Option 2** join the columns with `cbind()` and turn the whole thing around with `t()`. From a solution I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54727652/ggplot-aesthetics-incorrect-number-of-dimensions-when-indexing-a-data-frame).

```
solutions <- t(cbind("s1" = s1, "s2" = s2, "s3" = s3, "s4" = s4, "s5" = s5, "s10" = s10, 
                     "s11" = s11, "s12" = s12))
for( s in 1:length(solutions)) {
    # df <- as.data.frame(solutions[s])
    ggplot() + 
      geom_sf(data = range, size = 1, color = "black", fill = "NA") +
      geom_sf(data = fire, size = 0.25, color = "darkred",
              fill = "darkred", show.legend = 'poly') +
      geom_sf(data = poly, size = 0.25, fill = "darkorange", color = "darkorange") +
      geom_sf(data = IFL, size = 0.25, fill = 'darkseagreen', alpha = 0.7, color = "darkseagreen") +
      geom_sf(data = protected_areas, size = 0.5, alpha = 0.4, fill = "forestgreen", color = "forestgreen") +
      geom_sf(data = s[, "solution_1"], aes(fill = solution_1)) +
      geom_sf(data = linear, size = 0.5, color = "darkgoldenrod1") +
      ggtitle('Test solution') + 
      scale_fill_gradient(low = NA, high = "blue") + 
      theme_void() + 
      ggsave(s, path = path)
    
  Sys.sleep(2)
}
```

**Option 3** : Using `lapply()` because it looks like it's more efficient?

```
make_map <- function(s){
  ggplot() + 
    geom_sf(data = range, size = 1, color = "black", fill = "NA") +
    geom_sf(data = fire, size = 0.25, color = "darkred",
            fill = "darkred", show.legend = 'poly') +
    geom_sf(data = poly, size = 0.25, fill = "darkorange", color = "darkorange") +
    geom_sf(data = IFL, size = 0.25, fill = 'darkseagreen', alpha = 0.7, color = "darkseagreen") +
    geom_sf(data = protected_areas, size = 0.5, alpha = 0.4, fill = "forestgreen", color = "forestgreen") +
    geom_sf(data = s[, "solution_1"], aes(fill = solution_1)) +
    geom_sf(data = linear, size = 0.5, color = "darkgoldenrod1") +
    ggtitle('Test solution') + 
    scale_fill_gradient(low = NA, high = "blue") + 
    theme_void() + 
    ggsave(s, path = path)
}

lapply(solutions, make_map)
```

Essentially, in all the different options I've laid out below, I get the same error:

```
"Error in s[, "solution_1"] : incorrect number of dimensions"
```

However, if I plot each solution (i.e.

```
geom_sf(data = s1[, "solution_1"], aes(fill = solution_1)) + # this is the data from the solution in Prioritizr. It essentially adds a column called solution_1 and if a planning unit is selected for restoration it will be populated with a value of 1.
```

I don't get the error. Essentially, "solution_1" is a column in each dataframe that contains whether the unit has been selected or not by the model.

Any suggestions as to how I can rectify this?

Adding what one of the dataframes that I'm trying to plot in my loop looks like.
[image: S3 example df]

Comment: `"solution_1" is a column in each dataframe` yes but `s` is an integer that goes from 1 to soemthing, hence `s[, "solution_1"]` doesn't make sense. Are you trying to subset *rows* here? Without really seeing what your data looks like, or something like it if you can't share, we can't easily fix this up.

Comment: I am trying to subset a column "solution_1" from each dataframe (s1, s2, s3 etc) in my list. S is what I'm declaring to be an object in my list with the line:
``` 
for( s in 1:length(solutions): 
```
I'm very new to R so maybe im structuring my loop wrong?

Comment: if `solutions` is a list of things (data frames, other lists, fitted model objects, functions, anything) and `i` is a looping variable (from a `for` loop) then inside the loop the element you want is `solutions[[i]]` - which will be the data frame or list or whatever was put in the list at that position. Note the double square brackets which get a list element. This can use a number or a name if your list has names.